# Delphi 7 Enterprise LibHelp is missing

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

While compiling Delphi 5 code in Delphi 7 Enterprise Edition, i'm getting below errro

[Fatal Error] MultLang.pas(192): File not found: 'LibHelp.dcu'

I have checked all Delphi7 folders but libhelp.dcu is not present.. any advice???

Comment: Then LibHelp probably is not a Delphi unit. Maybe it belongs to the same library as MultLang and is in the same or a nearby directory.

Comment: The libhelp is listed in [Unit Names - Alphabetical List with Unit Scopes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Unit_Names_Alphabetical_List_with_Unit_Scopes), so it should be a Delphi unit (at least in XE2 as doc says). Can't find it in my XE7 Pro version though.

Comment: What does your code use LibHelp for. Why do you upgrade to Delphi 7 now? That seems to be a little pointless.

Comment: I have neither LibHelp.pas nor .dcu in my D2007. But it's used in some property editors, so I guess it's design-time stuff, and any code that uses it needs to be in a design-time package requiring designide.

Comment: Have you tried uncommenting the uses of LibHelp? IIRC, it wasn't needed for TMultLang at all. LibHelp was part of D5, but is not available in D7. LibHelp only declares some hc... constants.

Comment: The reason I ask why you need LibHelp is that a pre-requisite for porting is an understanding of your code. If you don't know what your code does, then the first step is to understand it. So, ask yourself, "why is my code using LibHelp?"

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I guess it is not his own code. MultLang is most likely a 3rd-party unit which has LibHelp in its uses clause.

Comment: @UweRaabe : yes..... I was looking in the code..... MultLang is 3rd party unit.... Actually we are moving our code from Delphi5 to Delphi7 as a part of our new environment setup.....

Comment: If I removed "LibHelp" and then compiled my components... its giving another error like "File not found: Proxies.dcu".... is this bcz in delphi7 we need to segregate our code like design time and runtime?????

Comment: I still think you are going to need to try to understand what your code is doing. Perhaps you do, but it's far from obvious that is so.

Comment: Google for Proxies.dcu - you'll find some discussions about separating design-time stuff from runtime stuff in packages. Follow the advice found there.

Comment: @abhaykondawar: Oops - you already figured that out. :-) Older Delphis were not that strict about separating design-time/runtime. I guess you're hit by that now.

Comment: @UliGerhardt: yes... now need to think like how to seperate design time and runtime as mentioned in below link http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27717

Comment: @UliGerhardt: meanwhile, i have created a sample project.exe in Delphi7 just to test... when i'm copying this in the other system where delphi7 is not installed then its giving below error ""The program can't start because rtl70.bpl is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
"".... And when i'm copying sample project.exe(Delphi5 version)... its working.....

Comment: Then you probably compiled with runtime packages in D7 but without in D5. But that's another question.

Comment: @UliGerhardt thanks.... completed the task by seperating design time and runtime related code... I guess now I can close this question :D

Comment: @abhaykondawar: In SO you don't close questions, you accept an answer. Hint, hint ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have neither LibHelp.pas nor .dcu in my D2007, but it's used in some property editors. So I guess it's design-time stuff, and any code that uses it needs to be in a design-time package requiring designide. Your comment about Proxies.dcu hints in the same direction, so I recommend separating design-time and runtime stuff in two different packages.